# Font size NOT changing through .vimrc but can inside vim

Tags: vimrc, gvim, linux-arch

I can change the font size with `set guifont=FixedsysTTF Monospace:h13` inside Vim and works perfectly.

However when I put this inside `~/.vimrc` it stays the same font size no matter what size I set it to, and it's really small.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem]

Comment: What does `:verbose set guifont?` (with the question mark as part of the command) show?

Comment: Try putting it in your gvimrc

Comment: @Heptite that outputs: guifont=FixedsysTTF \newline Last set from ~/.vimrc line 27

Comment: @D.BenKnoble tried, no luck still :(

Comment: Guess you need a backslash before the space in the font name.